# External Storage in Android

Tags: android, io, storage, external, logcat

I am trying to save an ArrayList to external storage in an Android application, and it seems to fail everytime, but I'm not sure why. I have followed the online tutorials about using external storage and I can't see anything different to the code I have. Here is my read function:

```
public static ArrayList<MapRoute> readFile(Context context, String filename) {

        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ArrayList<MapRoute> result = null;

        if (!externalStorageAvailable || !externalStorageWritable) {
            Log.d("READ FAILED", Environment.getExternalStorageState());
            return null;
        }

        try {
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            result = (ArrayList<MapRoute>)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("FAILED", "READ FAILED");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ois != null) {
                    ois.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ENDREAD", "FAIL");
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And write:

```
public static boolean saveFile(Context context, ArrayList<MapRoute> routes, String filename) {

        if (!externalStorageAvailable && !externalStorageWritable) {
            Log.d("FAILED", "FAIL");
            return false;
        }

        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        boolean success = false;

        try {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
            oos.writeObject(routes);
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("OOS", "FAILED");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (oos != null) {
                    oos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("OOS", "FAILED2");
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

In my logcat message the message FAILED READ FAILED from the try block inside the readFile function is outputted, and Im not sure if it is something to do with the way I'm trying to read the array list.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the stack trace

```
    03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353): java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an      exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: mark.es3.mapRoute.MapRoute
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:933)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:665)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1520)
03-13 22:20:33.690: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1443)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2112)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at mark.es3.activities.CreateSessionActivity$FavouriteRoutesTab.readFile(CreateSessionActivity.java:245)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at mark.es3.activities.CreateSessionActivity$FavouriteRoutesTab.onCreate(CreateSessionActivity.java:148)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1491)
03-13 22:20:33.695: W/System.err(25353):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:691)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:341)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:140)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 22:20:33.700: W/System.err(25353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: mark.es3.mapRoute.MapRoute
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
03-13 22:20:33.720: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:651)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at mark.es3.activities.CreateSessionActivity$FavouriteRoutesTab.saveFile(CreateSessionActivity.java:224)
03-13 22:20:33.725: W/System.err(25353):    at mark.es3.activities.CreateSessionActivity$FavouriteRoutesTab.saveRoute(CreateSessionActivity.java:207)
03-13 22:20:33.730: W/System.err(25353):    at mark.es3.activities.PlotRouteActivity.onHandleActionBarItemClick(PlotRouteActivity.java:94)
03-13 22:20:33.730: W/System.err(25353):    at greendroid.app.GDMapActivity$1.onActionBarItemClicked(GDMapActivity.java:247)
03-13 22:20:33.730: W/System.err(25353):    at greendroid.widget.ActionBar$1.onClick(ActionBar.java:396)
03-13 22:20:33.730: W/System.err(25353):    ... 11 more
```

My MapRoute class does implement Serializable so im not sure what that means.

Comment: privs all set in the manifest?

Comment: is your file getting created?

Comment: yep i have my <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in the manifest

Comment: @Tim the file is being created i can browse to it using the file directories on my android device

Comment: inside the catch block that has the "FAILED, READ FAILED" add e.printStackTrace(); and post the stack trace that appears in your log cat when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `MapRoute` object is not serializable, so you can't write it into an `ObjectOutputStream`. Possible solutions:

- make `MapRoute` and all classes used in it implement Serializable
- do the serialization/unserialization "by hand".